# CS50 - Speller | load function is not working in the right way

Tags: c

In my code I think that I did everything well but when I run my program it doesn't load the whole dictionary, which leads to an increase in the number of misspelled words. Somehow it passed 8/9 with check50 but I still want to know what is wrong with my code.

This is my load function:

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    do
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s", word);
        node *w = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (w == NULL)
        {

            return false;
        }
        strcpy(w->word, word);
        w->next = NULL;
        unsigned int hashno = hash(w->word);

        w->next = table[hashno];
        table[hashno] = w;
        dcount++;
    }
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF);
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

I really tried my best to find the bug but I couldn't.

Comment: What is `node`? What is `table`? Post a [mcve].

Comment: Aside:  We are leaking a `FILE *` in the block following `malloc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `fscanf()` twice for every iteration of the loop:

```c
do
{
    fscanf(file, "%s", word);
    ...
}
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF);
```

The word read in the second `fscanf()` is just discarded, and not stored in your dictionary.

You can simplify (and correct) your code by structuring it this way:

```c
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
    // Store 'word' in the dictionary
    ...
}
```